# How to compare two Pandas Dataframes with text, numerical, and None values

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, equality

I have two dataframes `df1` and `df2` that both contain text and numerical data in addition to `None`s as well. However, `df1` has integer numbers, and `df2` has float numbers.

I've tried comparing their equality with `df1.equals(df2)`, but this fails because of the type differences (integers vs. floats). I've also tried doing `np.allclose(df1, df2, equal_nan=True)` but this fails with `TypeError: ufunc 'isfinite' not supported for the input types, and the inputs could not be safely coerced to any supported types according to the casting rule ''safe''` (I imagine this is because of the text data).

How can I check to see if `df1` and `df2` have the same data?

Answer (score 1):

**Example**

```
data1 = {'text': ['hello', 'world', None],
         'num': [None, 2, 3]}
df1 = pd.DataFrame(data1)

data2 = {'text': ['hello', 'world', None],
         'num': [None, 2.0, 3.0]}
df2 = pd.DataFrame(data2)
```

**Code**

```
df1.equals(df2.astype(df1.dtypes))
```

output:

```
True
```

If you are concerned about errors occurring when converting dtypes, use the code below.

```
df1.equals(df2.astype(df1.dtypes, errors='ignore'))
```

If you can't change the dtype to be the same(when ignored), anyway they're not same

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, it doesn't seem like there's any easy function that will just check for equality in this scenario, so we'll have to build our own.

In order to do the check, we'll split the columns based on whether it's text data ('object') or number data. Then, we can compare the number data to the text data. We'll also deal with the `None`s by converting them to `Nan` so numpy can handle them better.

Here's the code:

```
def compare_mixed_dataframes(df1, df2) -> bool:
    # (This code was written by GPT-4, but I've tested it and it works)
    # Get the column names of numerical columns
    num_cols = df1.select_dtypes(include=[np.number]).columns
    
    # Convert numerical columns to float and replace None with NaN
    df1_num = df1[num_cols].astype(float).fillna(np.nan)
    df2_num = df2[num_cols].astype(float).fillna(np.nan)

    # Compare numerical columns with a tolerance value using numpy.allclose()
    num_comparison = np.allclose(df1_num, df2_num, rtol=1e-05, atol=1e-08, equal_nan=True)

    # Compare sentence columns using pandas.DataFrame.equals()
    string_cols = df1.select_dtypes(include=['object']).columns
    str_comparison = df1[string_cols].equals(df2[string_cols])

    # Combine the results of numerical and sentence columns comparisons
    return num_comparison and str_comparison
```

If you want to test the code for yourself, here's a quick script to test it:

```
# Also written by GPT-4, but edited by me to contain a more advanced test case
# I have also checked to make sure that this works
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

def compare_mixed_dataframes(df1, df2):
    # Get the column names of numerical columns
    num_cols = df1.select_dtypes(include=[np.number]).columns
    
    # Convert numerical columns to float and replace None with NaN
    df1_num = df1[num_cols].astype(float).fillna(np.nan)
    df2_num = df2[num_cols].astype(float).fillna(np.nan)

    # Compare numerical columns with a tolerance value using numpy.allclose()
    num_comparison = np.allclose(df1_num, df2_num, rtol=1e-05, atol=1e-08, equal_nan=True)

    # Compare sentence columns using pandas.DataFrame.equals()
    string_cols = df1.select_dtypes(include=['object']).columns
    str_comparison = df1[string_cols].equals(df2[string_cols])

    # Combine the results of numerical and sentence columns comparisons
    return num_comparison and str_comparison

# Create example DataFrames with mixed types (ints, floats, text, and Nones)
data1 = {'text': ['hello', 'world', None],
         'num': [None, 2, 3]}
df1 = pd.DataFrame(data1)

data2 = {'text': ['hello', 'world', None],
         'num': [None, 2.0, 3.0]}
df2 = pd.DataFrame(data2)

# DataFrames with different numbers
data3 = {'text': ['hello', 'world', None],
         'num': [None, 2, 4]}
df3 = pd.DataFrame(data3)

# Test the custom function with same and different DataFrames
print(compare_mixed_dataframes(df1, df2))  # True
print(compare_mixed_dataframes(df1, df3))  # False
```